# How to set the right index on nested fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a problem with nested **fields_for** in **rails**, I have a list of products and each product can have multiple images, so I use Angular.js to complete this task, I followed this tutorial https://tatey.com/2013/01/13/adding-and-removing-children-with-rails-nested-forms-and-angularjs/ , but the names of the inputs doesn't have the right name because the index doesn't increment at the first param only on the second, like this:

First product has two images so this are the names assigned to each input

```
catalog[products_attributes][0][images_products_attributes][0][url_image]
catalog[products_attributes][0][images_products_attributes][1][url_image]
```

The second product has one image and this are the names of the attributes

```
catalog[products_attributes][0][images_products_attributes][0][url_image]
```

As you can see the second product has the index **0** on the **products_attributes** but it should be **1**

This is my code

```
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
  <div class="product">
    <%= f.fields_for :products, Product.new do |product|%>
    <div class="field">
      Producto {{$index}}
      <%= product.text_field :name, placeholder: "Nombre"%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= product.text_field :description, placeholder: "Descripción" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= product.number_field :price, placeholder: "Precio" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= product.check_box :available %>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="name" value="+" ng-click="addImageToProduct($index)">
    <div class="images">
      <div class="image" ng-repeat="image in product.images">
        <%= product.fields_for :images_products, ImagesProduct.new, child_index: "{{$index}}" do |image|%>
        <div class="field">
          {{$index}}<%= image.file_field :url_image%>
        </div>
        <%end%>
        <input type="button" name="name" value="-" ng-click="removeImageToProduct($parent.$index, $index)">
      </div>
    </div>
    <%end%>
  </div>
  <input class="step-button remove" type="button" name="name" value="Quitar" ng-click="removeProduct($index)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the child_index from your forms

```
child_index: "{{$index}}"
```

And puts the code already generated in the view with:

```
catalog[products_attributes][{{$parent.$index}}][images_products_attributes][$index][url_image]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works!  I been trying it all and nothing but this is perfect!